# HTTP Error 403.16 - Forbidden- Sitecore xConnect

Tags: xconnect

I installed Sitecore 9 for xP0 , but I'm facing an issue with xConnect I tried to Open the web https://sitecorexp1.xconnect and I see an error **HTTP Error 403.16 - Forbidden Your client certificate is either not trusted or is invalid**.

Module IIS Web Core Notification BeginRequest Handler ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 Error Code 0x800b0109

The client certificate used for this request is not trusted by the Web server.

Can you help me out how to validate the certificate or generate a new certificate for xConnect?

Answer (score 7):

Windows 2012 introduced stricter certificate store validations. According to KB 2795828: Lync Server 2013 Front-End service cannot start in Windows Server 2012, the Trusted Root Certification Authorities (i.e. Root) store can only have certificates that are self-signed. If that store contains non-self-signed certificates, client certificate authentication under IIS returns with a 403.16 error code.

To solve the problem, you have to remove all non-self-signed certificates from the root store. This PowerShell command will identify non-self-signed certificates:

```
Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject}
```

So we need to move these non-self-signed certificates into the Intermediate Certification Authorities (i.e. CA) store: The below poweshell script helps to move the file.

```
Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject} | Move-Item -Destination Cert:\LocalMachine\CA
```

Please check the below link for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247462/http-error-403-16-client-certificate-trust-issue

Comment: This one solved my problem! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's possible your certificate is not matching the domain you're using. If it is, I would highly recommend having a read through [this blog post](https://kamsar.net/index.php/2017/10/All-about-xConnect-Security/).

The thing that helped me with a similar issue was because in my case the certificate itself was valid, but the app pool user account did not have access to the private key. My error though was

> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create
>   SSL/TLS secure channel.

I would check whether you've set the thumbprint correctly, as well as the name/location of the certificate store.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is mainly because, you local machine don't have the self-signed root certificate and client certificate. You can follow the below steps to create a self-signed root certificate.

Self-Signed Root Certificate

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=MyWebSSLRoot" -b 12/22/2013 -e 12/23/2040 -ss root -sr localmachine -len 2048
```

Create a client certificate

```
makecert -pe -n "CN=XConnect" -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 -is root -ir localmachine -in MyWebSSLRoot -ss my -sr currentuser -len 2048
```

Close all the browser instance and open the xConnect URL again.

You can also check if the solution in the below link helps.

https://medium.com/@sivalingaamorthy/sitecore-9-xconnect-not-working-having-error-http-error-403-16-b148bb247897